# Error in the visualizing Capacity bounds of FSO Links over Gamma-Gamma Atmospheric Turbulence Channels Using OOK Signaling?

Tags: capacity, mathematica

I simply want to visualize 【Capacity bounds and mutual information】 versus 【SNR $\gamma$(dB) or probability $p$ (The input to the channel is a binomial distribution with parameter $p$)】

But I cannot reproduce the results in a paper ([On the Capacity of FSO Links over Gamma-Gamma Atmospheric
Turbulence Channels Using OOK Signaling](https://sci-hub.se/10.1155/2010/127657)) for some reason.

**Is there some mistake in my Mathematica code?**

```
\[Gamma] = 10;(*\[Gamma]=P_{opt}/\sqrt{N_o W} is the SNR \
definition*)Clear["Global`*"];
p = 1/2;
\[Xi] = 1;
(*\[Xi] represents the square of the increment in Euclidean distance \
due to the use of a pulse shape of high PAOPR(peak-to-average optical \
power ratio),alternative to the classical rectangular pulse.*)
\[Theta] = 0.9028;
\[Kappa] = 2;(*with 0<\[Theta]<1,representing the fact that the \
channel under study is constrained to \[Kappa]=2 W T_b degrees of \
freedom*)\[Alpha] = 4;
\[CapitalTheta] = \[Alpha]^(3 \[Alpha]/
       2)*(1 - \[Alpha])^((1 - \[Alpha])/
      2)*(1 - \[Alpha]/2)^(1 - \[Alpha]/2);
\[Beta] = 4;
(*\[Alpha] and \[Beta] are related to the atmospheric conditions*)
SI = 1/\[Alpha] + 1/\[Beta] + 
  1/(\[Alpha]*\[Beta]);(*scintillation index,a parameter of interest \
used to describe the strength of atmospheric fading*)Capacity = 
 MeijerG[{{1, 
      1, (1 - \[Alpha])/2, (2 - \[Alpha])/2, (1 - \[Beta])/
       2, (2 - \[Beta])/2}, {}}, {{1}, {0}}, 
    16*(1/p - 
       1)*\[Xi]*\[Theta]*\[Kappa]*\[Gamma]^2/(\[Alpha]^2*\[Beta]^2)]*(\
2^(\[Alpha] + \[Beta])/
      Log[E, 2]/(2*Pi*Gamma[\[Alpha]]*Gamma[\[Beta]])) /. {\[Gamma] ->
     10*10^\[Gamma]};
Subscript[C, "nt"] = 
  1/2*Log[2, 
     1 + (1/p - 1)*\[Kappa]*\[Xi]*\[Theta]*\[Gamma]^2] /. {\[Gamma] ->
      10*10^\[Gamma]};
(*nt means:no atmospheric turbulence*)
Subscript[C, "AWGN"] = 
  1/2*Log[2, 1 + 2*\[Xi]*\[Theta]*\[Kappa]*\[Gamma]^2] /. {\[Gamma] ->
      10*10^\[Gamma]};
Subscript[C, "H"] = 
  Log[2, (Sqrt[\[Xi]*\[Theta]*\[Kappa]]*\[Gamma] + 2)*
     Sqrt[E/(2 Pi)]] /. {\[Gamma] -> 10*10^\[Gamma]};
Subscript[C, "F"] = 
  Log[2, Sqrt[
       E^2/(4 Pi)]^\[Alpha]*(Sqrt[\[Xi]*\[Theta]*\[Kappa]]*\[Gamma])^\
\[Alpha]*1/\[CapitalTheta]] /. {\[Gamma] -> 10*10^\[Gamma]};
Subsuperscript[C, "AWGN", "turb"] = 
 MeijerG[{{1, 
      1, (1 - \[Alpha])/2, (2 - \[Alpha])/2, (1 - \[Beta])/
       2, (2 - \[Beta])/2}, {}}, {{1}, {0}}, 
    32*\[Xi]*\[Theta]*\[Kappa]*\[Gamma]^2/(\[Alpha]^2*\[Beta]^2)]*(2^(\
\[Alpha] + \[Beta] - 2)/
      Log[E, 2]/(2*Pi*Gamma[\[Alpha]]*Gamma[\[Beta]])) /. {\[Gamma] ->
     10*10^\[Gamma]}; plot1 = 
 Plot[{Capacity, Subscript[C, "nt"], Subscript[C, "AWGN"], 
   Subscript[C, "H"], Subscript[C, "F"], 
   Subsuperscript[C, "AWGN", "turb"]}, {\[Gamma], 0.01, 50}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotRange -> Full, 
  AxesLabel -> {"SNR \[Gamma](in dB)", "Capacity(bits/channel use)"}];
Subscript[f, "I"] = 
  2*(\[Alpha]*\[Beta])^((\[Alpha] + \[Beta])/2)/(Gamma[\[Alpha]]*
      Gamma[\[Beta]])*i^((\[Alpha] + \[Beta])/2 - 1)*
   BesselK[\[Alpha] - \[Beta], 2 Sqrt[\[Alpha]*\[Beta]*i]];
CGammap[\[Gamma]_] := 
  NIntegrate[
   1/2*Log[2, (1 + (1/p - 1)*\[Kappa]*\[Xi]*\[Theta]*\[Gamma]^2*i^2)]*
     Subscript[f, "I"] /. {\[Gamma] -> 10*10^\[Gamma]}, {i, 0, 
    Infinity}];
plot2 = ListPlot[{#, CGammap@#} & /@ Range[5, 50, 0.1], 
   PlotLegends -> "anotherBound"];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

```
Clear["Global`*"];
\[Xi] = 1;
\[Theta] = 0.9028;
\[Kappa] = 2;

fYwhenxequals1[y_, p_, i_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  1/Sqrt[2*Pi]*
   Exp[-(y - 1/p*\[Gamma]*Sqrt[\[Xi]*\[Theta]*\[Kappa]]*i^2)^2/2];
fYwhenxequals0[y_] := 1/Sqrt[2*Pi]*Exp[-y^2/2];

MutualInformation[i_, p_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  Module[{denominator}, 
   denominator[y_] := (1 - p)*fYwhenxequals0[y] + 
     p*fYwhenxequals1[y, p, i, \[Gamma]];
   (1 - p)*
     NIntegrate[
      fYwhenxequals0[y]*
       Log[2, fYwhenxequals0[y]/denominator[y]], {y, -65, 109}] + 
    p*NIntegrate[
      fYwhenxequals1[y, p, i, \[Gamma]]*
       Log[2, fYwhenxequals1[y, p, i, \[Gamma]]/
         denominator[y]], {y, -65, 109}]];
listplotWhenSNRequalsMinus5dB = 
  ListPlot[{#, MutualInformation[1, #, 10^(-5/10)]} & /@ 
    Range[0, 1, 0.00625]];
listplotWhenSNRequalsMinus10dB = 
  ListPlot[{#, MutualInformation[1, #, 10^(-10/10)]} & /@ 
    Range[0, 1, 0.00625]];
listplotWhenSNRequalsMinus1dB = 
  ListPlot[{#, MutualInformation[1, #, 10^(-1/10)]} & /@ 
    Range[0, 1, 0.00625]];
Show[listplotWhenSNRequalsMinus5dB, listplotWhenSNRequalsMinus10dB, \
listplotWhenSNRequalsMinus15dB, 
 PlotLegends -> {"SNR is -5 dB", "SNR is -10 dB", "SNR is -1 dB"}]
```

[image]

```
Clear["Global`*"];
GammaGammaDistributionPDF[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := 
  2*(\[Alpha]*\[Beta])^((\[Alpha] + \[Beta])/2)/(Gamma[\[Alpha]]*
      Gamma[\[Beta]])*i^((\[Alpha] + \[Beta])/2 - 1)*
   BesselK[\[Alpha] - \[Beta], 2 Sqrt[\[Alpha]*\[Beta]*i]];
Plot[{GammaGammaDistributionPDF[4, 4], 
  GammaGammaDistributionPDF[4, 1], 
  GammaGammaDistributionPDF[1, 1]}, {i, 0.001, 10}, PlotRange -> Full,
  PlotLabel -> 
  Row[{"Gamma-Gamma distribution for different \[Alpha] and \[Beta]", 
    ""}], AxesLabel -> {"i", Row[{Subscript["f", "I"], "(i)"}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]


(*For plane wave,here sigmaR^2 is the variance of laser \
scintillation (Rytov variance?),and its magnitude determines the strength of \
atmospheric turbulence.The larger its value,the stronger the \
turbulence intensity.*)
GammaGammaDistributionPDFForPlaneWave[sigmaR_] := 
 GammaGammaDistributionPDF[
  1/(Exp[(0.49 sigmaR^2)/((1 + 1.11 sigmaR^(12/5))^(7/6))] - 1), 
  1/(Exp[(0.51 sigmaR^2)/((1 + 0.69 sigmaR^(12/5))^(5/6))] - 1)]
Plot[{GammaGammaDistributionPDFForPlaneWave[0.4], 
  GammaGammaDistributionPDFForPlaneWave[0.8], 
  GammaGammaDistributionPDFForPlaneWave[1.4]}, {i, 0.001, 6}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Row[{"Gamma-Gamma distribution for different ", 
    Subsuperscript[\[Sigma], "R", ""], ""}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"i", Row[{Subscript["f", "I"], "(i)"}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

[image]

---

By the way,

LogNormal model for weak turbulence

```
LogNormalDistributionForWeakTurbulence[MeanOfLogorithmLightIntensity_,
   StandardDeviationOfLogorithmLightIntensity_] :=
 Module[{MeanOfChi, VarianceOfChi, StandardDeviationOfChi}, 
  MeanOfChi = MeanOfLogorithmLightIntensity/2; 
  VarianceOfChi = StandardDeviationOfLogorithmLightIntensity^2/4;
  StandardDeviationOfChi = Sqrt[VarianceOfChi];
  PDF[LogNormalDistribution[MeanOfChi, StandardDeviationOfChi], i]]

Plot[Table[
   LogNormalDistributionForWeakTurbulence[0.05, 
    StandardDeviationOfLogorithmLightIntensity], \
{StandardDeviationOfLogorithmLightIntensity, {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8} // 
     Sqrt}] // Evaluate, {i, 0, 4}, Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotLegends -> {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Row[{"LogNormal distribution for different ", 
    Subsuperscript[\[Sigma], "l", "2"], ""}]]
```

[image]